# Distube Bot not resuming songs if hosted with heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, discord.js

My resume command won't work if my bot is hosted with heroku, but it perfectly works if the bot is running by the cmd or the vscode terminal.
My resume command code:

`else if (command ==  'resume') {`  `

`const queque = distube.getQueue(message)`

`if (!queque) return message.channel.send('Nothing is playing')`

```
    const resumeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`:play_pause: **RESUMED SONG**`)
    .setDescription(`I have resumed that song`)
    .setColor(`#02caf7`);
   distube.resume(message);
   message.channel.send(resumeEmbed)`
```

Comment: Are there any errors when you run it on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Heroku premium users, but I know free users can't cache information between events. Heroku, Autocode, nor Glitch permit caching between events so it may be best to host it yourself if you are intent on not using Rhythm or a similar music bot.

Comment: this is partially untrue, as you can make a cloud hosted file cache information using heroku or repl.it, but this information will be lost if the bot is restarted

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: I'll try to do that on my own, thanks anyway

Comment: I delete my previous comment because I could not edit the link, the resource i provided was for a different language than node.js! You'll need to use express and fs on heroku if you aren't already. This is a snippet of my own code for a similar project where i uploaded a static file: https://codeshare.io/5N1Rzd.